# What does "windup" verb mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I was listening to the [Go Time podcast #34](https://changelog.com/gotime/34) (see 1:50 - 2:02) and discovered unknown collocation where "windup" seem to be used as a verb.

```
You may windup writing a Java class
```

I would be grateful if someone explains that.

Comment: _wind up_: "arrive or end up in a specified state, situation, or place."

Comment: Missing a space between _wind_ and _up_, you could wind up (result in) writing a Java class, rather than whatever you originally planned to do.

Comment: Using the one word "windup" is not idiomatic for that specific use.  "Windup" is a word, but it's mainly a noun used in sports.

Comment: In your example, it's a verbal idiom  meaning to arrive or end up in a particular situation, in this case "writing a Java class". Btw, it's two words: "wind" + "up" (verb + preposition),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake, possibly of the typo variety, possibly misunderstanding of usage.

*Windup* is either a noun or adjective, with both forms having similar meanings: the windup of an awards show; a windup session after a week of classes. (It's also a term of art in baseball: the windup before a pitch.)

The verb form is always two words (also known as a *phrasal verb*). It has multiple meanings. One is to put something under tension, especially if it contains a spring: *to wind up a watch*; *to wind someone up over an issue*. Another is the meaning in the (mistaken) quote in the question: to end up in a certain condition, particularly one where the subject isn't actively going there. The correct phrasing for the original sentence fragment is

```
You may wind up writing a Java class
```

Comment: Cambridge Dictionary says "to come to be in a particular situation or condition, esp. a bad one". I find the term used in good situations nearly as often, in practice; e.g. "she wound up head of the company". The key is almost always that the subject was passive, rather than active. The connotation is indeed bad, but again, it's weak, and often not followed, even non-ironically.

Comment: "She wound up head of the company" is probably a good situation, but "She wound up *the* head of the company" is probably not good - it would mean "she *annoyed* the head of the company." English is a strange language!

Comment: Indeed; perhaps she grabbed the head of the CEO and firmly twisted it 720 degrees to ensure proper tension. In fairness, whether this situation is "bad" may depend on one's perspective.